# Word count on a CSV of tweets returning error out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
import csv
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict


words= []
with open('Hometovotetweets.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
         csv_words = row[1].split(" ")
         for i in csv_words:
              words.append(i)

words_counted = []
for i in words:
    x = words.count(i)
    words_counted.append((i,x))

#write this to csv file
with open('HTVwordcount.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(edgl)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "wordcount.py", line 11, in 
>           csv_words = row[1].split(" ")
>       IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: But where's the question?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. IndexError means that you are accessing the row with an index number that is not present (out of range). Maybe it's a problem with `.split(" ")`. I suggest printing out the row before accessing it. Then you should probably see what's going wrong.

Comment: The row is highlighted as the [1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well obviously your `row` only have one single element in it (remember that in Python - like in almost all languages - indexing is zero-based), so check your csv file content's and make sure you use the proper field delimiter.

Comment: I am an idiot ran it with [0] and it seems to be parsing the text now. Also thanks

Comment: It ran but through the following error: writer.writerows(edgl)
NameError: name 'edgl' is not defined

Comment: Well it seems obvious - where is this name defined ?

Comment: Sorry I am very new python and programming in general. edgl is not defined anywhere. If i just leave writer.writerows() empty like that will it work?

Comment: I have. I was confused by the edgl in the script and that was why i left it there.   writer = csv.writer(f)
         writer.writerows(words_counted)

Comment: Seems more sensible indeed ;)